# how not to overflow a cell?

Tags: html, css

I have a table that is capturing the whole screen ( HEIGHT = "100%", WIDTH="100%") and i have set specific height in each row by percentage. So in second cell of the second row there is a paragraph. I want the height to be stable but inside the div i want a vertical scroll bar.

```
<table>
  <tr style="height:20%;">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:60%; ">
    <td></td>
    <td><div style= "width:100%; overflow:auto;"><p>THIS CELL OVER HERE</p></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:20%;">
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to have `table-layout:fixed;` along with `overflow:hidden;` `white-space: nowrap;` on the table element

From the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout):

> In a fixed table layout, the horizontal layout only depends on the
>   table's width, the width of the columns, and not the content of the
>   cells

Also if you want to have a vertical scroll bar in your `div` then you may try this inside your `div`:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is correct, but you need to set a fixed height to the div (you can do something like: on the td with div set position: relative, on dive set height: 100%; should work) so the overflow: auto would work. Except that... you should be fine with what you have.